# Check if ALL the waiting threads are in waiting state and not working

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have a `ProcessesManager` class that `extends Thread`. Inside the `run()` method, I am doing this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true)
    synchronized (GlobalVariables.queue) {
        while (GlobalVariables.queue.isEmpty())
            // Threads are waiting here...
            GlobalVariables.queue.wait();

        // Get the next work item off of the queue
        work = GlobalVariables.queue.remove();
    }
}
```

In the main method, I am creating four instances(threads) of the `ProcessesManager` class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ProcessesManager processesManager = new ProcessesManager();
        processesManager.start();
}
```

and they are waiting for the `queue`. The queue is empty at the start and then I start filling up the queue and the threads start working on the queue items. Now the threads remove from/add items to the queue simultaneously. There is no "end" to the program per se. But to be clear, the end of the program is when 1. The Queue is empty. 2. ALL the threads are waiting and NOT working anymore.

Now I want to implement a method that checks three conditions:

1. Check if the queue is empty.
2. Check if ALL the threads are waiting and NO thread is doing any work.
3. Check if it is NOT the start of the app (since at the start, above two conditions will be true for a while).

If all the above conditions are satisfied, I want to exit/close the app.

I can check Condition 1 by simply checking `GlobalVariables.queue.isEmpty()` method. But I don't know how to check if ALL the threads are in waiting state. I can find a solution for the third condition also.

How can I check if ALL the threads are just waiting and not working anymore?

**EDIT**

I am using this tutorial: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/java-concurrency-queue-processing-part-1/232700457. Is there a method to know the end of the program?

Answer (score 0):

Use ReentrantLock with condition , it has many methods which may solve your problem
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Answer (score 0):

> to be clear, the end of the program is when 1. The Queue is empty. 2. ALL the threads are waiting and NOT working anymore.

Suppose your worker threads were, on average, faster than the producer that is filling the queue.  In that case, the queue would be empty most of the time, and the workers would be waiting much of the time.  In your scheme, if the queue is empty and the workers are all idle, there's no way to tell whether that's because the producer truly is finished, or whether it's just because the producer is a little bit slow in adding the next item.

Maybe in your application, the producer will never get behind like that, but there's nothing in your code that *guarantees* it will never get behind like that.

The thing that you are implementing is called a *thread pool* (e.g., like `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`).  In most thread pool implementations, there is some way for the producer to *explicitly* shut down the pool (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()`)

One way to implement the shutdown is to use a *poison pill* -- a special task that tells the worker thread that pulls it to terminate.  When it's time to shut the pool down, the caller simply loads up the queue with at least as many poison pills as there are worker threads servicing the queue.

Comment: Yes I have studied ThreadPool  a bit. But decided not to implement it. The thing is: my producers and consumers are the same threads. e.g. If I start up four threads, these same threads are going to consume and produce and look at the same queue. A "producer" thread can "put" some work in the queue but also "get" some work from the queue and "consume" it. Anyways, I worked around it. But I would like to know if it is okay to close my program without terminating the threads. Is it an "okay" practice?